# Saving multidimensional byte array to SQL Server database 

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multidimensional-array, arrays

I want to save a multidimensional byte array to a SQL Server database.

I know how to save a byte array which is a image conversion to a database. For that the data type I used is `image`. But now I want to store another byte array which is multidimensional byte array `byte [,] temp`, which has two dimensions with x,y values.

I searched on internet and here, it is said that using `VARBINARY` format. All I want to know is if I save my multidimensional array in a `VARBINARY` datatype data column, will the values will be altered? Is it possible to receive the data back as multidimensional array again?

Comment: `IMAGE` is deprecated - for SQL Server **2005 and newer**, you should **always** use `VARBINARY(MAX)` for storing any binary type - whether that's a single picture or a multi-dimensional array. And **no** your data will **not** be altered in any way  - bytes in, bytes out, exactly as you put them in in the first place

Comment: Awesome thanks.. It was really helpful... And one more thing why do you say IMAGE is deprecated.. Is there any downside of using IMAGE..? I am using sql server 2005

Comment: PS: I googled and got the answer. thanks again. Hope you put this as an answer so i can tick it. Between here is the link for more deprecated data types for those who wants : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/15f9e54c-18af-4f9a-8472-58fbd285a736

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to get back your multi-dimensional array unaltered.

**How can you do it?** Using a Varbinary(max) field in Sql Server and saving into it the serialized multidimensional byte array. In order to get your array back, obviusly, you need to deserialize what you stored in the database.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
public void TestSO()
{
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            //This is the original multidimensional byte array
            byte[,] byteArray = new byte[2, 2] {{1, 0}, {0,1}};
            ConnectionStringSettings conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
            conexion.ConnectionString = conString.ConnectionString;
            conexion.Open();
            command.Connection = conexion;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table SET VarBinaryField = @Content WHERE Id = 73 ";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1));
            //Serialize the multidimensional byte array to a byte[]
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, byteArray);
            //Set the serialized original array as the parameter value for the query
            command.Parameters["@Content"].Value = ms.ToArray();
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                //This method returns the VarBinaryField from the database (what we just saved)
                byte[] content = GetAttachmentContentsById(73);
                //Deserialize Content to a multidimensional array
                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(content);
                byte[,] fetchedByteArray = (byte[,])bf.Deserialize(ms2);
                //At this point, fetchedByteArray is exactly the same as the original byte array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just of curiosity, how do you actually convert byte[,] to byte[] when storing/retrieving from SQL Server in ADO.NET? I thought varbinary() only accepts byte[] and not byte[,].

Comment: I'd say that, knowing the dimensions, a byte[a,b] is nothing more than a byte[a*b]...

Comment: Yes, and "knowing the dimensions" is key point here. How should SQL know how to split varbinary(n) into byte[,] (varbinary(10) could be byte[1,10], byte[2,5], byte[5,2], byte[10,1]...).

Comment: That's what I meant. Now the answer is complete. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I knew it was possible but wasn't sure exactly how. I updated my answer with the "how". The key is to store the byte[,] as a serialized byte[] in a varbinary(max) field. When you need it back, you get a byte[] and deserialize it to a byte[,]

Comment: Keep in mind, serializing the data using BinaryFormatter will add additional metadata, increasing the size of the data stream to be larger than the size of the original byte array, because it has to pack the following metadata: RecordTypeEnum (1 byte), ObjectID (4 bytes), BinaryArrayTypeEnum (1 byte), Rank (4 bytes), Lengths (4 bytes per array dimension), LowerBounds (4 bytes per array dimension), etc.  See: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236897.aspx  So it may be more efficient to perform the multi to single (and vice versa) conversion oneself if the # of dimensions is known.

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no appropriate data type in Microsoft SQL Server to store multidimensional arrays. However there are many ways to save information about array structure. Some of them:

1. create several columns of BINARY (fixed-length) data type and each
   row of your multidimensional array to appropriate column; in this
   case it is expected that count of rows in your array is constant;
2. store the whole array as one-dimensional array into single column of
   VARBINARY (variable-length) data type and store in separate column
   of INT data type the count of elements in each row of
   multidimensional array; in this case it is expected that count of
   elements in each row is the same (not jagged C# array); when reading
   array then you will be able to split elements by this length into
   separate rows of multidimensional array.

Comment: So what you mean is when we retrieve the saved multidimensional array from the database, we will receive it as a one dimension array and we have to alter it to make the original multidimensional array using the save number of elements in a raw..?

Comment: Yes, you can't put multidimensional array 'as is' into column and then retrieve it back. If it is strongly required to get multidimensional array, you can retrieve one-dimensional array from database and process it using C# to create multidimensional. For example, if you store 5 as a count of elements in row and total count of elements in stored array is 20, you'll be able to copy each 5 elements from retrieved array and put them into row-array. At the end you'll have [4, 5] array.

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight. That is the exact issue i had. But after the earlier answers i thought VARBINAY somehow handles the datatype conflict. I will try implementing this and check. Thanks again..!PS(up vote the problem if you can)

Comment: I would even extend the second solution by writing custom "serializer" which stores byte[,] by writing to byte[]: number of dimensions, length of each dimension and then every byte one by one. This way you do not need additional columns to store dimensions.

Comment: @Gihan I updated my answer with the actual solution. Varbinary is the way to do it without any doubt. The key is to serialize the byte[,] so you store a byte[] in the database. Please check my updated answer and if it is what you need, please re-accept it.

Comment: @daniloquio thanks alot... i re accepted the answer... That was great help... I am adding the solution to my project now....